# Can I use a 6mm threaded bolt instead of a bleed valve for hydraulic brakes?

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

I've accidentally lost the bleed valve in a front-brake "bleed gone wrong" afternoon and was wondering whether there's anything detrimental in just using a 6mm bolt instead for the time being?

Comment: what brakes are you running?

Comment: Shimano Deore M556, quite retro now I think.

Comment: Sorry got to ask.  Why did you take it out?

Comment: I would guess that you need either a bolt with a tapered end or a gasket of some sort, in order to achieve the proper seal.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I reckon plumber's threadlock teflon tape should do the trick of sealing just fine. Works well on DOT systems, and I doubt teflon has issues with mineral oil.

Comment: @moshbear - Except that the threads of a standard bolt are not tapered, like the threads of a pipe are.  And you risk getting fragments of the tape in the fluid, where they could easily cause a braking failure.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I forgot the part about standard bolts and bleed screws having different thread geometry :|

Comment: If I found a bolt that seemed to fit pretty well I'd consider getting an O ring that fit snugly in the hole, insert that, then the bolt.  Depending on the geometry of the hole that might or might not work.

Comment: Also, my Teflon tape comment is based off Hayes' caliper overhaul instructions: "Note: ... The thread sealant on the bleeder
is there only to seal during the bleeding process. If thread sealant wears off, replace it with a
wrap of Teflon tape thread sealant."

That being said, gasketing isn't needed *if* it can get tight enough to not leak.

Comment: (Citation: http://www.hayesdiscbrake.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/45-24479_Ace_Caliper_service.pdf)

Comment: I admit that it assumes pipe / bleed valve thread geometry, not that of a generic bolt.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Thanks, I did just that in the end. Rubber O ring on the bolt and it seems to have sealed. Makes bleeding trickier for the future so will have to source a valve at some point...

Answer (score 3):

Well you won't be able to bleed your brakes for one thing.  You can buy bleeder screws at auto parts stores.  I've never bought one, but 6 mm sounds like a normal size.  I'd check there.